# Product Name WooCommerce in Contact Form 7

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, contacts

I have the woocommerce plugin and the contact form 7 plugin too.

On the product detail page, in the tabs at the bottom I have a custom tab called enquire. I am embedding one of the forms I created.

Although I am just trying to echo the product title in the form so people don't have to fill it up by themselves.

This does not seem to be working ..

```
    <p>Your Name (required)<br />
    [text* your-name] </p>

<p>Your Email (required)<br />
    [email* your-email] </p>

<p>Subject<br />
  </p>

<?php echo get_the_title( 'id' ); ?>

<?php echo WC_Product::get_formatted_name(); ?>


<p>Your Message<br />
    [textarea your-message] </p>

<p>[submit "Send"]</p>
```

Does anyone have any idea ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Nd how did you added tab ? Can you please provide code for that also ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't know how did you add tab as **you have not mentioned anything** ..

But you can achieve by adding following code in to your **theme**'s `functions.php` :

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'product_enquiry_tab' );
function product_enquiry_tab( $tabs ) {

    $tabs['test_tab'] = array(
        'title'     => __( 'Enquire about Product', 'woocommerce' ),
        'priority'  => 50,
        'callback'  => 'product_enquiry_tab_form'
    );

    return $tabs;

}
function product_enquiry_tab_form() {
    global $product;
    //If you want to have product ID also
    //$product_id = $product->id;
    $subject    =   "Enquire about ".$product->post->post_title;

    echo "<h3>".$subject."</h3>";
    echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="19" title="Contact form 1_copy"]'); //add your contact form shortcode here ..

    ?>

    <script>
    (function($){
        $(".product_name").val("<?php echo $subject; ?>");
    })(jQuery);
    </script>   
    <?php   
}
    ?>
```

Also **add class** to your **contact form** :

```
    <p>Your Name (required)<br />
        [text* your-name] </p>

    <p>Your Email (required)<br />
        [email* your-email] </p>

    <p class="product_subject">Subject<br />
        [text your-subject class:product_name] </p>

    <p>Your Message<br />
        [textarea your-message] </p>

    <p>[submit "Send"]</p>
```

**Bingo !** You have just achieved what you wanted.

**Screen shot**

[image]

Comment if you have any doubt.

Comment: I did succeed another way eventually but this way is much cleaner.

Comment: Glad you found it useful .. Happy Coding !

Comment: great solution for product detail page.
you have any idea to show the contact form in shop page display inquiry button on each product and on click open popup with form filled by product name?

Comment: Thanks for your contribution.
I am getting this warning and notice. can you help me what should i do.
Please check error and notices.

https://pastebin.com/mC2hNq6n

Answer (score 9):

I'm quite surprised! no one mentioned `[_post_title]`.

and here are the list of [special mail tags](http://contactform7.com/special-mail-tags/) you can use...

Answer (score 0):

this button must be inserted into the .php page
I inserted the woocommerce folder into tabs.php

```
    <a href="https://www.yoursite.it/contact/?code=<?php echo urlencode(get_the_title()); ?>"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg scuro"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>Contattaci per questo prodotto
Contact us for this product</button></a>
```

this code must be inserted into cf7

```
<label> title product
[text code default:get]</label>
```

no plug-in is needed

Answer (score -1):

Try this one

```
<?php echo WC_Product::get_formatted_name(); ?>
```

Comment: Nothing gets echo .. /
This is the structure of the form :

<p>Your Name (required)<br />
    [text* your-name] </p>

<p>Your Email (required)<br />
    [email* your-email] </p>

<p>Subject<br />
  </p>

<?php echo get_the_title( 'id' ); ?>

<?php echo WC_Product::get_formatted_name(); ?>


<p>Your Message<br />
    [textarea your-message] </p>

<p>[submit "Send"]</p>

Comment: How do you send the product ID to the contact form.