# Pass the chosen product variations data into Contact Form 7 enquiry form

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, contact-form-7, product-variations

With WooCommerce, I use Contact Form 7 and [Product Info Request](https://it.wordpress.org/plugins/product-info-request-for-woocommerce/) plugins to add a form inside a single product pages, because I need a functionality that allow users to send an enquiry request about products (thought simple contact form).

You can understand seeing this screenshot:
[image: screeshot]

All my products are variable product with variations *(from attributes)*.

Is there any way to retrieve the selected variations by the customer and send it via contact form 7?

For example:

User select the color black and size s, then fill the form and when the email is send, in addition to Receive the classic information (name, email ecc..) I receive also the attribute selected (in this case **`black`** and **`s`**)

Comment: Hi LoicTheAztec, first of all thank you very much. I try and follow all steps, but when i fill the form i don't receive a variation in mail. I add [text your-product class:product_details] in module tab and also Product: [your-product] in mail tab.

Comment: Your solution is great, it's exactly what you were looking for, but it does not work with woocommerce 3.5.4, the field "[text your-product class: product_details]" does not appear in the form. It would be possible to adapt it for that version.
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **UPDATED:** *Added WC 3+ compatibility*

I have tested it and it will not send any data related to chosen variations, because it is just outputting the selected contact form below add-to-cart button (in single products pages). Additionally this plugin hasn't been updated since more than 2 years, so it's some kind of outdated.

> **THE GOOD NEW: A WORKING SOLUTION**

**I have found this related answer:** [Product Name WooCommerce in Contact Form 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28828072/product-name-woocommerce-in-contact-form-7)

It explains how to set a contact form 7 shortcode in a product tab and displaying the chosen product title in the email.

So from this answer I have transposed the code, to use it just as the plugin was doing (just below the add to cart button).

Here in this example/answer I have set in my variable product 2 attributes for the product variations: **`Color`** and **`Size`**.

This are my settings **`Contact form 7`** for the form that I will use in my code:

```
<label> Your Name (required)
    [text* your-name] </label>

<label> Your Email (required)
    [email* your-email] </label>

<label> Subject (required)
    [text* your-subject class:product_name] </label>

<label> Your Message
    [textarea your-message] </label>

[submit "Send"]

[text your-product class:product_details]
```

Here I have add this text field **`[text your-product class:product_details]`**. so you will need to add also in your "mail" settings tab **`[your-product]`** tag inside the "message body", to get that in your email:

```css
From: [your-name] <[your-email]>
Subject: [your-subject]

Product: [your-product]

Message Body:
[your-message]

--------------
This e-mail was sent from a contact form 7
```

The PHP code custom funtion hooked in **`woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_form`** action hook:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_form', 'product_enquiry_custom_form' );
function product_enquiry_custom_form() {

    global $product, $post;

    // Set HERE your Contact Form 7 shortcode:
    $contact_form_shortcode = '[contact-form-7 id="382" title="form"]';

    // compatibility with WC +3
    $product_id = method_exists( $product, 'get_id' ) ? $product->get_id() : $product->id;
    $product_title = $post->post_title;

    // The email subject for the "Subject Field"
    $email_subject = __( 'Enquire about', 'woocommerce' ) . ' ' . $product_title;

    foreach($product->get_available_variations() as $variation){
        $variation_id = $variation['variation_id'];
        foreach($variation['attributes'] as $key => $value){
            $key = ucfirst( str_replace( 'attribute_pa_', '', $key ) );
            $variations_attributes[$variation_id][$key] = $value;
        }
    }
    // Just for testing the output of $variations_attributes
    // echo '<pre>'; print_r( $variations_attributes ); echo '</pre>';


    ## CSS INJECTED RULES ## (You can also remve this and add the CSS to the style.css file of your theme
    ?>
    <style>
        .wpcf7-form-control-wrap.your-product{ opacity:0;width:0px;height:0px;overflow: hidden;display:block;margin:0;padding:0;}
    </style>

    <?php


    // Displaying the title for the form (optional)
    echo '<h3>'.$email_subject.'</h3><br>
        <div class="enquiry-form">' . do_shortcode( $contact_form_shortcode ) . '</div>';


    ## THE JQUERY SCRIPT ##
    ?>
    <script>
        (function($){

            <?php
                // Passing the product variations attributes array to javascript
                $js_array = json_encode($variations_attributes);
                echo 'var $variationsAttributes = '. $js_array ;
            ?>

            // Displaying the subject in the subject field
            $('.product_name').val('<?php echo $email_subject; ?>');

            ////////// ATTRIBUTES VARIATIONS SECTION ///////////

            var $attributes;

            $('td.value select').blur(function() {
                var $variationId = $('input[name="variation_id"]').val();
                // console.log('variationId: '+$variationId);
                if (typeof $variationId !== 'undefined' ){
                    for(key in $variationsAttributes){
                        if( key == $variationId ){
                            $attributes = $variationsAttributes[key];
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                }
                if ( typeof $attributes !== 'undefined' ){
                    // console.log('Attributes: '+JSON.stringify($attributes));
                    var $attributesString = '';
                    for(var attrKey in $attributes){
                        $attributesString += ' ' + attrKey + ': ' + $attributes[attrKey] + ' — ';
                    }
                   $('.product_details').val( 'Product <?php echo $product_title; ?> (ID <?php echo $product_id; ?>): ' + $attributesString );
                }
            });

        })(jQuery);
    </script>

    <?php
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

> You will get exactly what the plugin was doing with that additionals features:
>
> - **A custom product title**, as subject of the mail.
> - **The selected variation attributes Name label + values** in the additional fiels (that will be hidden).

Here are the screen shoots from my test server:

The product with the selected attributes:
[image]

What I get on the form (I dont hide the special text field to show you the pulled data by jQuery):
[image]

**As you see, you get the data you need to send in your email…**

Once I have selected the attributes of the product and filled the other fields of the form, when I submit this form I get, this email message:

> ```
> From: John Smith <j.smith@themain.com>
> Subject: Enquire about Ship Your Idea
>
> Product: Product Ship Your Idea (ID 40):  Color: black —  Size: 12 —
>
> Message Body:
> I send this request about this very nice product … I send this request about this very nice product …
>
> --
> This e-mail was sent from a contact form 7
> ```

**So everithing is working just as you expected and this is a working tested example answer.**

Comment: Is there any way to get the price of the selected variation?