# Display a form when the selected variation is out of stock in WooCommerce

Tags: php, jquery, woocommerce, contact-form-7, product-variations

In WooCommerce with [Contact Form 7 plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/), I have added a form to my out of stock simple products, on single product pages, using the following code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'add_contact_form', 30, 2 );
function add_contact_form() {
    global $product;

    if( ! $product->is_in_stock( ) && ! $product->is_type('variable') ) {
       echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="14880" title="Fiyat Sorunuz"]');
    }
}
```

This "out of stock" form works just well for simple products:

[image: out of stock form works]

---

**But doesn't work on "out of stock" product variations** for variable products:

[image: only out of stock. How can I add a variant form?]

How can I display this form for selected product variation that are out of stock?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This requires a little change in your code and some jQuery code to show/hide the contact form (and the add to cart button) on variable products, depending on the selected product variation stock status.

The replacement code for simple and variable products:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'add_product_outofstock_contact_form', 30, 2 );
function add_product_outofstock_contact_form() {
    global $product;

    $contact_form = do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="14880" title="Fiyat Sorunuz"]');

    if( $product->is_type('variable') ) {
        echo '<div class="outofstock-form" style="display:none">' . $contact_form . '</div>';
    } elseif( ! $product->is_in_stock() ) {
        echo $contact_form;
    }
}

add_action('woocommerce_after_variations_form', 'outofstock_product_variation_js');
function outofstock_product_variation_js() {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($) {
        var contactFormObject  = $('.outofstock-form'),
            addToCartButtonObj = $('.woocommerce-variation-add-to-cart');

        $('form.variations_form').on('show_variation', function(event, data) { // No selected variation
            if ( ! data.is_in_stock  ) {
                addToCartButtonObj.hide('fast');
                contactFormObject.show('fast');
            } else {
                addToCartButtonObj.show('fast');
                contactFormObject.hide('fast');
            }
        }).on('hide_variation', function() { // Not on selected variation
            addToCartButtonObj.show('fast');
            contactFormObject.hide('fast');
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Related: [Pass the chosen product variations data into Contact Form 7 enquiry form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42165213/pass-the-chosen-product-variations-data-into-contact-form-7-enquiry-form/42174658#42174658)

Comment: Omg! Amazing Thanks.

Comment: Thanks man, Do you know any place where to find all native name(eg.show_variation) for wooCommerce @LoicTheAztec