# WooCommerce - auto-fill product name into form field on another page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, contact-form-7

I have an "Enquire" button on some of my product pages where the customer can click and be brought to the contact details page for the website. On this contact page I have a Contact Form 7 form setup and working

What I'd like to happen is that a field in this form (Subject or a new "Product" field) auto-fills with the name of the product the customer was just looking at - as in the product from where they clicked the "Enquire" button

Has anyone attempted something like this previously and how did you get on? I see lots of examples here where enquiry forms on the product page itself are auto-populated with the name of the product but I'm hoping to copy data from one page into a form on another page so more complex I imagine

Thx

**@LoicTheAztec**... you have marked this as a duplicate of a question you have answered but I disagree. I asked specifically how to carry the product name into a form field **on another page** whereas the solution you linked to describes populating a form field on the product page itself. I even mentioned solutions such as yours as in my original question and how these were not of use to me

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to go through the stackoverflow more deeply for this. Anyways there are two answers regarding this on stackoverflow and I am representing it here. Give them credit for this if its solve your problem

[First one is this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28828072/product-name-woocommerce-in-contact-form-7)

And some one try it after little modification

[Here is the second one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42165213/pass-the-chosen-product-variations-data-into-contact-form-7-enquiry-form)

Go through these two options hope it will help you

Thanks

Comment: None of these answer my question and I stated this in my question. I asked how to populate a form field on a separate page... not how to populate an in-page form field. I read both of your suggested solutions before posting this question. This website can be frustrating at times